# Remove insets of UITableViewStyleGrouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know if it's possible to remove the grey insets that are automatically used with the UITableViewStyleGrouped style when using UITableViews on iOS?

I know that UITableViewStylePlain doesn't have these insets, but I'm trying to avoid the "sticky header views" that come with using UITableViewStylePlain.

Or, perhaps there is a way to disable the sticky header views when using UITableViewStylePlain?

Comment: If you do not want to have sticky headers, you will need to just put them in as standard cells.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the inset by

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

but it will remove the border of all table view cells too